# How do I add a custom `labels` for just one tick?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm making a chart where the X axis will have '%'.

```
ggplot(
  data = cars,
  aes(
    x = speed,
    y = dist
  )
) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(
    labels = function(x) paste0(x,'%'),
  )
```

This produces a chart.
[image]

I only want either the first tick or last tick on the X axis to have the '%'. How do I do this?

Comment: If you make this a [reproducible question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), including a representative sample of the data, someone can most likely help out

Comment: @camille Updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change your function to

```
labels = function(x) c(paste0(x[1] * 100, '%'), x[-1])
```

(note you may have to adjust your breaks and/or limits because in the updated example you posted, the first element of x is not plotted, so in that case you would need to do `c(paste0(x[1:2] * 100, '%'), x[-(1:2)])`)

Comment: Thanks. This changes only the first tick. That's great. How would I write this code so that only the final tick label is formatted? `function(x) c( x[1], paste0(x[-1]*100, '%') )` removes the '%' from the first tick, but none of the others.

Comment: For an answer to my question, see Sri Lakshimi's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Format the function in labels to get '%' for the first tick label only

```
labels = function(x) c(paste0(x[1],'%'),x[-(1)]
```

To get '%' for last tick label only

```
labels = function(x) c(x[1:length(x)-1] , paste0(rev(x)[1],'%'))
```